# Project-Swift.h file failed to compile due to "Elaborated type refers to a typedef" error

Tags: ios, xcode8, ios10

Summary:
I have added the StreamDelegate method `public func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event)` to my swift class and compiled the project. While generating `Project-Swift.h`, complier failed to compile and show error as `Elaborated type refers to a typedef`.

Steps to Reproduce:
1. Add `StreamDelegate` to your swift class.
2. Add public `func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event)` to your class.
3. Compile the project.

Expected Results:
`Project-Swift.h` file should be compiled properly.

Actual Results:
error on Project-Swift.h file at the line : `- (void)stream:(NSStream * _Nonnull)aStream handleEvent:(enum NSStreamEvent)eventCode;`

Temporary fix:
if i remove `enum` keyword on `Project-Swift.h` at the like of `- (void)stream:(NSStream * _Nonnull)aStream handleEvent:(enum NSStreamEvent)eventCode;`, the project compiled properly and build succeeded.

iOS Version: `iOS 10 beta 1`
Xcode Version: `Xcode 8 beta`
Swift Version: 2.3 or 3.0

Answer (score 1):

I found a work around to avoid the above error by adding the `@nonobjc` keyword in front of `func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event)` in my Swift class. So that the compiler doesn't included that method in `Project-Swift.h` file and there is no error in `Project-Swift.h` while compiling.

```
@nonobjc public func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {
    //Other stuffs
}
```

I don't think this will be the proper solution for above issue. But for me I don't want to call the above delegate method from my Objective-C class.

Thanks!